# Ignore a subdirectory in an external table in Apache Hive

Tags: sql, apache, hadoop, hive, hdfs

Does Hive have a setting or a way of forcing it to ignore subdirectories when querying an external table? I have a subdirectory in my table folder that's not part of the table's data and I want to avoid deleting it or copying the files elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem. I ended up subclassing TextInputFormat and overriding listStatus, allowing me to filter out directories from the file list.

For those who are curious, check out my message to the Hive mailing list:

[Re: Ignore subdirectories when querying external table](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201108.mbox/%3CCAC80dVSwRz3GpTSAzpS1eQw_P79ko+-=jmQVkOE2VMvMam=0iQ@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Comment: Thanks a Lot for this.  Help me sometime to write my own. ;)